# establish direct query connection from Postgres to Power bi

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, database-connection, directquery

I want to establish direct connection from postegresql DB with power bi.
I am using DBeaver as environment and I can only connect to power bi using ODBC.
I need direct query so I could visual big data from DB in power BI.

This is the message I get when I want so connect via PostgreSQL database:

```
An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'
```

Is there a way to connect directly so I could pull more data from one dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ODBC connections to connect in direct query mode. You have to use the normal Postgre connector.
This link outlines the database and connection types you can use direct query with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources